# Storage Extension changes in SDL Tridion 2013

Tags: 2011, 2013-sp1, storage-extensions

Using SDL Tridion 2013 SP1, I am working with Storage Extension (Written with SDL Tridion 2011 and upgraded to make it compatible with SDL Tridion 2013 SP1). In this storage extension, I am trying to get the component presentation of a dynamic component being published.

Earlier in SDL Tridion 2011, this can be retrieved by using the `com.tridion.Storage.ComponentPresentation.getContent()` method which returns the Component Presentation as string. However, in SDL Tridion 2013 SP1, this method has been updated to return the component presentation as `byte[]` instead of `string`.

Is there some another method through which I can get string presentation of the CP or I am in trouble to change the code everywhere and explicitly convert the byte[] to string by standard java code - Also, will it be possible if I convert this byte[] to string, it will give me the Component Presentation published?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed the `com.tridion.storage.ComponentPresentation` class was changed. The *create*, *remove* and *update* methods now receive the Component Presentation content as byte-array.

If you need the string contents, you can simple do:

```
    @Override
    public void create(
         ComponentPresentation itemToCreate,
         ComponentPresentationTypeEnum componentPresentationType) throws StorageException
    {
        String actualContent = new String(itemToCreate.getContent(),"UTF-8");
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I remember facing the same issue. I went with converting the `byte[]` into a `String` the "java-way". As far as I remember the `byte[]` contains the published content, so yes, by converting it to a `String` it would give you the published content. Just remember the Encoding you want to use for such conversion, if you are publishing UTF-8, then use UTF-8, if you know what I mean...

And I am afraid you will have to update your code to use the new method...

Comment: Thanks Jaime for the answer; accepting Rai's answer because of its completeness and code sample :)